# Shader нужно писать под каждый обьект?

Tags: android, opengl, opengles, шейдеры

У меня есть пример в котором создается обьект (Зеленый 3D андроид).

Вопрос мой касательно `Shader`-ов. Как я понимаю, это работает — есть набор `Vertices`, сначала он обрабатывается с помощью `VerticesShader`, потом результат отправляется в `FragmentShader`. Эти шедеры (я так понял) пишутся под конкретный обьект. Скажем, если мы рисуем треугольник, то шейдеры одни, если 3D андроида то — другие.

Вопрос первый — правильно ли я это понимаю?

И второе — если первое верно, то как писать эти шейдеры? Вот представил я себе, допустим, нарисовать куб, написать коордитаны точек для него я могу представить как сделать, но как потом к ним написать шейдеры?

**ПРАВКА**

```
private int loadProgram(int iVertexShaderHandle, int iFragmentShaderHandle)
{
    // Create a program object and store the handle to it.
    int programHandle = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

    if (programHandle != 0)
    {
        // Bind the vertex shader to the program.
        GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, iVertexShaderHandle); --- ЭТО НЕ ПИШЕМ?

        // Bind the fragment shader to the program.
        GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, iFragmentShaderHandle); --- ЭТО НЕ ПИШЕМ?

        // Bind attributes
        GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 0, "a_Position");
        GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 1, "a_Color");

        // Link the two shaders together into a program.
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(programHandle);

        // Get the link status.
        final int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetProgramiv(programHandle, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);

        // If the link failed, delete the program.
        if (linkStatus[0] == 0)
        {
            GLES20.glDeleteProgram(programHandle);
            programHandle = 0;
        }
    }

    if (programHandle == 0)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error creating program.");
    }

    return programHandle;
}
```

Comment: вершинный шейдер получает на вход точки модели и может менять их положение, получившиеся точки образуют поверхности, для каждого пикселя, в который попала эта поверхность будет вызван фрагментный шейдер, который должен вернуть цвет пикселя

Comment: отдельный шейдеры обычно нужны для объектов, которые по разному выглядят в одних и тех же условиях, например поверхность воды и поверхность камня в общем случае нет смысла пытаться описать одной шейдерной программой, больно уж разная физика преломления-отражения света будет использована при расчете цвета фрагмента

Comment: что касается вершинного шейдера - им удобно создать например форму  поверхности воды, на вход получив точки лежащие в одной плоскости и внутри шейдера дать им разную высоту в зависимости от времени, получится что поверхность колеблется во времени, при тех же входных данных о вершинах

Comment: с другой стороны - в движке юнити сделано по-другому, у них одни супер-пупер шейдер, который как только нельзя настроить, и им они окучивают все объекты, однако возможность использовать другие никуда не убрана и есть возможность написать свои шейдеры

Comment: @StrangerintheQ так вот мой вопрос вообще пришел из юнити, так как у нас есть имплементация написаная на юнити, а мне ее нужно написать на андроиде(я еще и с++ туда прицепил), но как раз дело в том, что у меня есть вертиксы и все остальное, но теперь мне нужно где то взять эти шедеры... Человек который делал это на юнити говорит, что он не писал никакие шедеры все якобы генериться... Так вот теперь я понял из вашего комента, что у юнити свое кино... Так, а как тогда быть в такой ситуации? Как написать шедеры?

Comment: в каком виде представлены объекты?

Comment: как они должны выглядеть - быть освещены?

Comment: в самом простом случае шейдеры не нужны, точнее они ничего не делают, просто пропускают через себя информацию, ничего не меняя

Comment: если есть модель, нарисованная в редакторе с наложенными текстурами и никакое освещение - затенение не требуется больше то и шейдеры не потребуются

Comment: @StrangerintheQ оо, вот еще интересный факт)) Шедеры не нужны... Это то, что мне говорили тут... Я не мог понять как так не нужны если во всех примерах показано имплементации с их применением... Да у нас все сделано в редакторе и освещение тоже и текстуры... Если говорить технически, то шедеры я загружаю в програму, значит если они мне не нужны я просто не загружаю их и все?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Добавил код в вопрос. Оставил коменты на двух сточках, парвильно я понял?

Comment: если вы никакую программу не активируете, то работает встроенная, которая ничего не делает, но обычно все же их явно указывают, минимальные, вот как здесь, только сегодня с этим возился https://github.com/nervous-systems/ffmpeg-opengl/blob/master/vf_genericshader.c

Comment: а так то они дают доступ к огромной мощи, которая заложена в современный gpu, вот неплохое видео на тему https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-P28LKWTzrI

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Подскажите пожалуйста, я многое не понимаю в опенгл, можете посмотреть мою сборку проекта вот [ссылка на чат в котором я выложил ссыки](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97190/opengl---)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Шейдер — это программа, которая обрабатывает поток данных. Например, у вас есть моделька вашего андроида. Эта моделька должна быть представлена в виде [стрипа](http://www.learnopengles.com/tag/triangle-strips/) — последовательности точек для отрисовки объекта.

Каждая вершина поочерёдно скармливается шейдеру, и он обрабатывает одну за раз. То есть на вход он получает вершину, состоящую из двух или трёх координат, это минимум, плюс [матрицу проекции](https://habr.com/ru/post/305796/) через юниформу. Его задача — привести координаты сцены к координатам OpenGL (экран для OpenGL — это поле от -1 до +1 по обеим осям) с учетом поворота камеры, деформации от проекции и т.п. То есть на выход он положит опять же вектор из 2 или 3 координат.

После отработки вершинного шейдера мы знаем положение на экране каждой точки из стрипа. Запускается процесс растеризации, в ходе которого каждый ваш треугольник в стрипе (треугольник на вершинах 1-2-3, 2-3-4 и т.д.) "простраивается" на экране и каждый пиксель, который треугольник заполнил в достаточной доле, пройдёт через фрагментный шейдер. Параметры во фрагментный шейдер придут интерполированные значения от этих же параметров в вершинах, от которых треугольник построен (про интерполяцию посмотрите [тут](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/400-urok-171-opengl-tsvet.html) на примере цвета).

В итоге, что вы должны сделать, чтобы отрисовать модель из юнити в нативном андроиде:

1. Преобразовать модель в стрип из вершин по правилам из ссылки выше. В OpenGL 2.0 нет рестарт индекса, так что вырождение вершин — ваше всё. Если вы захотите использовать индексы, знайте, что OpenGL гарантирует только 16-битное число номера вершины. То есть с индексом вы можете использовать 2<sup>16</sup> − 1 вершин, 65к примерно. Этого может оказаться мало для сложной модельки и придётся разбивать. На некоторых телефонах можно и 32-битное использовать, но это значит, некоторые телефоны будут просто вылетать или рисовать чушь.
2. Для каждой вершины придётся вычислить текстурные координаты, если в модельке они не привязаны.
3. Написать минимум два шейдера. Один вершинный, который преобразует координаты вершин, и второй — фрагментный, который позволит определиться с цветом, который придёт интерполированный из вершин или из текстуры по текстурным координатам, интерполированным из вершин. Тут же может быть применено освещение, если оно нужно, используя нормали из вершин или карты освещённости.

Боюсь представить как это все читается, если никогда с этим не работали) Что непонятно — спрашивайте, расскажу или ткну, где почитать

Как создать шейдер

```
private static int createShader (int type, String shaderText) {

    // Создаём "слот" под новый шейдер
    final int shaderId = GLES20.glCreateShader (type);
    if (shaderId == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    // Закидываем в него код шейдера
    GLES20.glShaderSource (shaderId, shaderText);
    // компилим
    GLES20.glCompileShader (shaderId);
    final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
    // Получаем результат компиляции. Да, вот такой вот странный метод, в OpenGL его часто придётся использовать
    GLES20.glGetShaderiv (shaderId, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);
    if (compileStatus[0] == 0) {
        GLES20.glDeleteShader (shaderId);
        return 0;
    }
    return shaderId;
}

// Создаём вершинный шейдер, передав нужный тип и код шейдера текстом
final int building_vertex = createShader (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, buildings_vertex_text);
// Также с фрагментным    
final int building_fragment = createShader (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, building_fragment_text);
// Создаём шейдерную программу
shader = createProgram (building_vertex, building_fragment);
// u_MVP — юниформа, объявленная в одном из шейдеров. Вытаскиваем номер, под которым она сохранилась в OpenGL, чтобы знать куда складывать нужные значения
MVP = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation (shader, "u_MVP");
// Сообщаем программе, что у нее есть атрибут a_Position
GLES20.glBindAttribLocation (shader, 0, "a_Position");
// И также вытаскиваем номер, чтобы знать куда слать данные для атрибута
a_Position = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation (shader, "a_Position");
```

Всё, теперь можно использовать `GLES20.glUseProgram` с нашим шейдером.

Comment: Формально, шейдер - не программа, только её часть.